# what can I do to Solve this to get The SHA-1 for firebase project setup?

Tags: firebase, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

while I executed the command ./gradlew signingReport I executed command to get SHA-1 it gave me
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. currently using Java 1.8.

I tried to create the new variable for JAVA_HOME but it did not work since it was one of the recommendations by Android Studio Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Just Download The jdk11 and add org.gradle.java.home=path\jdk11 to the gradle.properties file in your project

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, it's best to use the latest versions that are supported. So you should consider downloading [JDK 17](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk17-archive-downloads.html), create a the `JAVA_HOME` variable and set the compile options inside Android Studio:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

If you're using Kotlin, you should also set the Kotin options:

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Comment: yes the idea is to have a java version is equal or greater than the plug in version ,thank u so much.